# Extract filename from data frame

Tags: r

R rookie here.

I have a loop that I'm using to create output files.  I'm using a data frame as an input to the loop, the loop runs a query for each "id" value in the data frame.  One of the columns in my data frame contains the output file name.  I'm having some trouble getting the loop to dynamically read in the file name and insert it into the write.table statement.

Working example:

```
ID = c(123,124)
ExtractName = c("sessions.txt","hits.txt") 
Dimensions = c("ga:date", "ga:date") 
Mertics = c("ga:sessions", "ga:hits") 
Extracts = data.frame(ID, ExtractName, Dimensions, Mertics) 

for(i in seq(from=1, to=nrow(Extracts), by=1)){
  id <- Extracts[i,1]
  myresults <- ga$getData(id,batch = TRUE, start.date="2013-12-01", end.date="2014-01-01", metrics = Extracts[i,4], dimensions = Extracts[i,3])

  write.table(myresults, file=***dynamicnamehere***, append=TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = appendcolheads, sep="\t")
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you have duplicate `filenames` in your input dataset.  Is it a typo or is it possible to have different `ids` have the same file name?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have the same filename -- I didn't list all of loop, but in some cases it will append to the same file.

Comment: If the `myresults` are in a `list` with the length of the list equal to the `nrow` of the `input` dataset, perhaps, `lapply(seq_along(myresults), function(i) write.table(myresults[[i]], file=input$filename[i], ....))` (not tested without an example dataset)

Comment: I presume the solution is to use brackets instead of parentheses (i.e., `input[i,2]`), otherwise R interprets `input` as a function with arguments `i` and `2`.

Comment: See edit in first post for working example.

Comment: Davids12, the for-loop returns an error because there is no object "ga" defined in your code. ´(Error: object 'ga' not found)´.

Comment: Right, I'm using the Google Analytics (ga) package to pull down some data.  I was hoping the example would be robust enough for someone to suggest a solution of how to extract the file name from the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Davids, I made a slight change to your code example as  it was generating an error.

2 things to lookout for: when creating the DataFrame add  "stringsAsFactors=FALSE" otherwise the filenames are factors, which you do not want.

```
Extracts = data.frame(ID, ExtractName, Dimensions, Mertics,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the `file`- Argument in your for-loop: `file=Extracts$ExtractName[i]`

This slightly changed code should give you your desired results.

```
ID = c(123,124)
ExtractName = c("sessions.txt","hits.txt") 
Dimensions = c("ga:date", "ga:date") 
Mertics = c("ga:sessions", "ga:hits") 
Extracts = data.frame(ID, ExtractName, Dimensions, Mertics,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

for(i in seq(from=1, to=nrow(Extracts), by=1)){
  id <- Extracts[i,1]
  myresults <- c(id, start.date="2013-12-01", end.date="2014-01-01", metrics = Extracts[i,4],     dimensions = Extracts[i,3])
  write.table(myresults, file=Extracts$ExtractName[i], append=TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep="\t")
}
```